# Chaining block passing in ruby

Tags: ruby, block

lets say I have an array

```
array = [[2], [1], [0]]
```

I can do this:

```
array.map(&:any?)
# => [true, true, true]
```

and I can do this:

```
array.map do |x|
    x.any?(&:zero?)
end
# => [false, false, true]
```

why cant i do this? (or something similar):

```
array.map(&:any?(&:zero?))
```

returns SyntaxError: unexpected '(', expecting ')'

array.map(&:any?(&:zero?))

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you defining `array` and then using `a` that is not defined?

Comment: @sawa, oops, thanks, will fix (question and answer below all still the same and all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `:any?(&:zero?)` is not an appropriate symbol literal. You can make it a symbol by doing `:"any?(&:zero?)"`, but still, there is no such method.

Comment: Ok, so, I can do  proc = Proc.new {|v| v.any?(&:zero?)} then array.map(&proc), why not something like array.map(&(any?(&:zero?)).to_proc)
? Thank you for the answer though, this is all very interesting and googling around did not help much.

Comment: `any?(&:zero?)` means `self.any?(&:zero?)`. In order for that to work, `self` has to be something that responds to `any?`, and its result has to be something that responds to `to_proc`.

Answer (score 3):

Reasons why are explained in other answers. You can however use the shortcut for anything if you define a proc:

```
any_zeros= ->(o) { o.any?(&:zero?) }
array = [[2], [1], [0]].map(&any_zeros)
```

Comment: As you used `lambda` method, the variable name should be `lambda` instead of `proc`. :-)

Comment: The variable name should be neither "proc" or "lambda", it should be mnemonic: Something like 'any_zeros?' Name it something that describes what it's doing, even for temporary things like this.

Comment: Good point, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Simple answer: because Ruby doesn't include syntax for it.

You are basically trying to pass a default argument to the method. The Ruby devs, at some point, made a decision that a feature like this was too much work and extra complication for what can be achieved using this little code:

```
array.map {|e| x.any?(&:zero?)}
```

Comment: Actually, he's trying to use a symbol literal with a parenthesis, which is not a valid syntax. That is the cause of the syntax error.

Comment: @GuilhermeFranco: That's the cause of the syntax error, true, but that doesn't meant there's a syntax for doing what the OP is asking about doing. From the Q: `why cant i do this? (or something similar):`

Comment: I think he can't do that because it is an invalid syntax =P

Comment: @GuilhermeFranco: Doesn't change the fact that there *is* no syntax to do that.

Comment: thank you. you mean e.any?(&:zero?) though I think.

Comment: @Linuxios You're right. But that is not related to default argument to methods. The cause of the syntax error is because OP is trying to use parenthesis in a symbol literal. It would be the same if OP did `"MyString"('foo')`.